A mysterious commutativity condition for division ring
Prove (or disprove): A division ring $D$ with character $p \neq 0$ is a field iff for $\forall x, y \in D$, $(x+y)^p = x^p + y^p$.
It is an exercise from a ring theory textbook. However no hint or answer is given. It seems that expansion of $(x+y)^p$ involves $2^p$ terms that are very difficult to cancel. Also I have tried this article.
The article defines a map $A(x) := (a+b)x - xb$ and states that $(a+b)^p = \sum\limits_{i=0}^p \binom{p}{i}A^{i}(1)b^{p-i}$, therefore we only need to prove that $A^p(1) = a^p$ implies commutativity, but it is also involves high-order commutators.

I guess you see how commutativity implies the equation (known as the Freshman's Dream), and the question is about the opposite direction? Or are you asking about both?

Yes the problem is about the opposite direction. Thanks for your direction! However I am not sure whether this proposition is correct or not?

In France a field is not necessarily commmutative but in USA it does. A consequence is that the set of quaternions is a field (non-commutative) and in USA it is not. You need to consider just $D$ infinite (Wedderburn's theorem). Because of what I have mentioned, I don't try to solve this problem. Good luck.

Dear Prof Piquito the field here is commutative.

I.N. Herstein, Power maps in rings, Michigan Math. J. 8(1): 29-32 (1961):

Theorem 2. Let $R$ be a ring in which for some fixed integer $n>1$, $(x+y)^n=x^n+y^n$ for all $x,y \in R$. Then every commutator in $R$ is nilpotent, and the nilpotent elements of $R$ form an ideal.

